# How do I use Entity Framework with MySQL Connector noinstall version?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, connector

Does anyone know any way to have the Entity Framework working with mysql connector 6.3/6.4 no install version? I can add the dll-s to my project, but I can't add the connection to the Entity framework because it doesn't see mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to get mySQL and entity framework working are available in this [blog post](http://christianpayne.com.au/2010/05/07/vs-2010-mysql-entity-framework-and-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-because-of-an-error/)

If you are trying to do it without have a database installed, I do not think that that is possible.